# How to enable dark mode for all for .md pages in @nuxt/content

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Setting colorMode in any way for `.md` pages doesn't work in `Nuxt3`.

I do have a Nuxt3 app + `@nuxt/content` module, and would like to have ALL pages in dark more by default. What I've tried:

1. in .md files

```
---
title: Home
navigation: false
colorMode: dark
layout: page
---
```

and

```
---
title: Home
navigation: false
colorMode:
  preference: dark
  forced: true
  fallback: dark
layout: page
---
```

2. in `src/app.vue`

```
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
   colorMode: 'dark',
})
</script>
```

3. in `nuxt.config.ts`

```
  colorMode: {
    classSuffix: '',
    preference: 'dark',
    fallback: 'dark',
  }
```

and

```
 content: {
    documentDriven: {
      globals: {
        theme: {
          colorMode: {
            classSuffix: '',
            preference: 'dark',
            fallback: 'dark',
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

nothing of this works.

I can only set color for individual .vue pages with

```
definePageMeta({
   colorMode: 'dark',
})
```

but my main content is in `/content/*.md` file that I can't theme to dark apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. In .md files

The `colorMode` variable in .md files will not automatically match the `@nuxtjs/color-mode` settings. This is because the `@nuxt/content` module and the `@nuxtjs/color-mode` module are not integrated.

### 2. In app.vue

According to the official documentation of `@nuxtjs/color-mode`, `definePageMeta({ colorMode: 'dark' })` only works in .vue files in the /pages directory. Therefore, it cannot be used in app.vue.

### 3. In nuxt.config.ts

This method will only work properly if `localStorage` does not have any color-mode settings. This is because the `@nuxtjs/color-mode` module will prioritize reading and using the settings in localStorage, regardless of how you set your `preference` value.

### Conclusion

If you want to ensure that all pages use dark mode, you can set it up like this in `app.vue`:

```
const colorMode = useColorMode();
colorMode.preference = 'dark';
```

Comment: Thanks, Eric! indeed I also got the same answer in this issue - https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/2464